Why is my 'position: sticky' navbar not staying fixed at the top in React?
I’m working on a React application and have a Navbar component that uses position: sticky with top: 0. It was working fine previously, but at some point, it stopped staying fixed at the top when scrolling.
I’ve tried the following solutions:

Ensured the parent container has enough height and is not using overflow: hidden or similar styles.
Applied a high z-index (z-50) to the Navbar to avoid conflicts with the background.
Adjusted the layout to ensure there are no collapsed margins or conflicting styles.
Checked with Chrome’s Developer Tools and confirmed that the sticky class is being applied correctly.

The Navbar was working as expected earlier, but for some reason, it stopped working. Despite trying these fixes, it still does not stay fixed at the top when scrolling.
I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. 
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useMediaQuery } from '@react-hook/media-query';

import logo from '../assets/logo.png';
import line from '../assets/line-h.svg';
import lineh from '../assets/lineh.svg';
import Telegram from '../assets/Telegram.svg';
import X from '../assets/X.svg';
import ConnectButton from '../components/ConnectButton';

const Navbar = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isScrolled, setIsScrolled] = useState(false);

  // Detecta si estamos en móvil o tablet (max-width: 1024px)
  const isMobileOrTablet = useMediaQuery('(max-width: 1024px)');
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(max-width: 768px)');
  const isTablet = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px)');

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  // Bloquear/desbloquear el scroll del body según el estado del menú
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; // Desactiva el scroll
    } else {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'; // Activa el scroll
    }
    return () => {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'; // Limpieza al desmontar el componente
    };
  }, [isOpen]);

  // Detectar scroll y actualizar estado del navbar
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (!isOpen) {
        setIsScrolled(window.scrollY > 50);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, [isOpen]);

  return (
    <div
      className={`px-4 sm:px-12 py-4 sticky top-0 z-50 ${
        isOpen
          ? 'bg-[#000a0a]'
          : isScrolled
          ? 'bg-[#000a0a]/50'
          : 'bg-transparent'
      }`}
    >
      <nav className="flex justify-between items-center text-white relative z-20">
        {/* Logo de la Empresa */}
        <div className="text-lg font-bold z-20 w-[151px]">
          <img src={logo} alt="NOVA Real Chain" className="w-[99px] h-[32px]" />
        </div>

        {/* Si está en móvil o tablet, muestra el botón hamburguesa */}
        {isMobileOrTablet ? (
          <button className="text-white text-4xl z-20" onClick={toggleMenu}>
            {isOpen ? '✖' : '☰'}
          </button>
        ) : (
          <div className="flex items-center rounded-full border custom-border bg-[linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(255,255,255,0.02)_0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1)_100%)] px-[1px] gap-[1px]">
            <a
              href="#"
              className="px-4 py-2 text-[13px] font-normal font-medium leading-[20px] rounded-[60px] hover:bg-white/10"
            >
              Home
            </a>

            <a
              href="#"
              className="px-4 py-2 text-[13px] font-normal font-medium leading-[20px] bg-black/60 rounded-[60px] shadow border custom-border hover:bg-black"
            >
              RWA Launchpad
            </a>

            <div className="relative flex items-center group z-50">
              <a
                href="#"
                className="px-4 py-2 text-[13px] font-normal font-medium leading-[20px] z-50 rounded-[60px] hover:bg-white/10"
              >
                Other Products
              </a>

              <div className="absolute left-0 top-full mt-0 p-4 w-[182px] bg-[#040105] shadow-lg rounded-md hidden group-hover:block z-50 custom-border">
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
                  <a
                    id="menu"
                    href="#"
                    className="block px-4 py-1.5 text-[13px] border-l-[1px] border-transparent text-white z-50 menu"
                  >
                    RWA Nodes
                  </a>
                  <img src={line} alt="" />
                  <a
                    id="menu"
                    href="#"
                    className="block px-4 py-2 text-[13px] border-l-[1px] border-transparent text-white z-50 menu"
                  >
                    RWA Real Estate
                  </a>
                  <img src={line} alt="" />
                  <a
                    id="menu"
                    href="#"
                    className="block px-4 py-2 text-[13px] border-l-[1px] border-transparent text-white z-50 menu"
                  >
                    RWA Miners
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <a
              href="#"
              className="px-4 py-2 text-[13px] font-normal font-medium leading-[20px] rounded-[60px] hover:bg-white/10"
            >
              About Us
            </a>

            <a
              href="#"
              className="px-4 py-2 text-[13px] font-normal font-medium leading-[20px] rounded-[60px] hover:bg-white/10"
            >
              News
            </a>
          </div>
        )}

        {/* Botón para conectar wallet solo en escritorio */}
        {!isMobileOrTablet && <ConnectButton isMobile={false} />}
      </nav>

      {/* Menú desplegable en móviles y tabletas */}
      {isMobileOrTablet && isOpen && (
        <div
          className={`fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full bg-[#000a0a] text-white flex flex-col justify-between z-1000 ${
            isMobile ? 'px-4' : isTablet ? 'px-12' : ''
          } ${isMobile || isTablet ? 'pt-[120px]' : ''}`}
        >
          {/* Parte superior */}
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center w-full">
            <ConnectButton isMobile={true} onClick={toggleMenu} />
            <img src={lineh} className="w-full" alt="" />
            <a
              href="#"
              className="w-full py-2.5 px-5 text-center text-white text-base font-medium leading-normal mt-4"
              onClick={toggleMenu}
            >
              Home
            </a>
            <a
              href="#"
              className="w-full py-2.5 px-5 text-center text-white text-base font-medium leading-normal"
              onClick={toggleMenu}
            >
              RWA Launchpad
            </a>
            <a
              href="#"
              className="w-full py-2.5 px-5 text-center text-white text-base font-medium leading-normal"
              onClick={toggleMenu}
            >
              Marketplace
            </a>
            <a
              href="#"
              className="w-full py-2.5 px-5 text-center text-white text-base font-medium leading-normal"
              onClick={toggleMenu}
            >
              About Us
            </a>
            <a
              href="#"
              className="w-full py-2.5 px-5 text-center text-white text-base font-medium leading-normal"
              onClick={toggleMenu}
            >
              News
            </a>
          </div>

          {/* Parte inferior */}
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center space-y-4 mb-6">
            <img src={lineh} className="w-full" alt="" />
            <p className="text-[#f1ffff]/70 text-sm font-normal leading-tight">
              Join our community
            </p>
            <div className="flex gap-[6px] rounded-[30px] custom-border p-0.5 bg-[linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(255,255,255,0.11)_0%,rgba(204,204,204,0.09)_20.17%,rgba(0,0,0,0)_100%)] shadow-[0px_30px_60px_0px_rgba(0,0,0,0.5)] backdrop-blur-[10px]">
              <div className="px-[16px] py-[6px] bg-black/60 rounded-[100px] shadow custom-border">
                <img src={Telegram} alt="Telegram" />
              </div>
              <div className="px-[16px] py-[6px] bg-black/60 rounded-[100px] shadow custom-border">
                <img src={X} alt="Twitter" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;


Can you isolate the example in a codepen?

How is the Navbar rendered in relation to the rest of the webpage?
